# Recommendations regarding TextField in modal Dialog

Tags: codenameone

What are the recommendations for inputting texts and especially for entering texts in modal dialogues?

When having a modal dialog with a text field one probably wishes to start editing immediately when the dialog is shown - what's the best way to do that?

In the past I received recommendations like not to use text fields in modal dialogs. Is this still true? What are the alternatives?

That works - but is probably not the way to go:

```
            TextField textFieldDialog = new TextField() {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    startEditingAsync();
                    super.paint(g);
                }
            };
            Dialog.show(
                    "Text Input",
                    FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(textFieldDialog),
                    Command.create("Cancel", null, (aActionEvent2)->{}),
                    Command.create("OK", null, (aActionEvent2)->{}));
```

Comment: Would it be good if the the Dialog class had create methods like the existing show methods to create a Dialog instance? One could then apply addShowListener before invoking the show method.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is not to put a text field in a dialog, modal or otherwise. It's a problematic as the screen sometimes resizes to fit the UI and this doesn't work well at all with dialogs.

You can launch editing using `startEditing` or `startEditingAsync` on `TextField`.

Comment: If I wanted a modal dialog I guess I could create a form  which has a screenshot of the previous form as a background. But - a Dialog is a Form, right? So what is the difference?

Comment: That would have the exact same problem where you rely on an explicit position in the screen of the text field which will change as the keyboard opens so it will fail in a worse way. A Dialog positions its UI by using margin to push it away from the edges. On screen resize the padding is no longer correct so we need to recalculate and things get "hairy" as we need to "guess the intention of the developer"

Comment: I am afraid I still don't quite understand - what would be required - that the Dialog is srollable? We could do that, right?

Comment: It would work but you might run into issues. The dialog has margin from the sides and under some circumstances with some keyboards and some OS's the dialog might get too cramped and you might experience odd side effects.